# Heat equation with two boundary conditions on one side

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, parabolic-pde

Solve the heat equation 
$$ u_t = u_{xx} $$
in $0\le x\le 1$ and $t\ge0$ with the initial condition $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$ and boundary conditions **only on the left boundary** $x=0$
$$ u(0,t)=f(t), \quad u_x(0,t)=g(t). $$

I do not know this problem is well-posed or not. Thanks!

Comment: To solve it, you may try the method of separation of variables. I don't think this problem is well-posed since you do not have a boundary condition on $x=1$.

Comment: @CheeHan You are right. It is not well-posed.

Comment: Why is it not well-posed!?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Apply the method similar to [diffusion equation, inhomogenous boundary conditions (the subtraction method)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243150) , i.e. let $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+f(t)+xg(t)$ ,

Then $u_t(x,t)=v_t(x,t)+f_t(t)+xg_t(t)$

$u_x(x,t)=v_x(x,t)+g(t)$

$u_{xx}(x,t)=v_{xx}(x,t)$

$\therefore v_t+f_t(t)+xg_t(t)=v_{xx}$ with $v(0,t)=0$ and $v_x(0,t)=0$

Comment: How do I see at yout hint that the problem is not well-posed? I have the same problem right now and intuitively I would suppose the problem is well-posed..